# How to set arial font only in the table

Tags: tables, fonts

I have a table. Latex code is given below. I want to set the font of this table arial - only this table not the entire document. How do I set this?

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\small
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\toprule
    {\centering\tabhead{Col1}}&
    {\centering\tabhead{Col2}}&
    {\centering\tabhead{Col3}}&
    {\centering\tabhead{Col4}}\\

\midrule

wwww & xxxx & yyyy & zzzz \\

wwww & xxxx & yyyy & zzzz \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_table}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: See _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document

Comment: Do you _require_ Arial_ or do you mean 'a sanserif font': often people are happy with a clone of Helvetica.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that with `pdflatex`, you first have to install the [winfonts](ftp://ftp.dante.de/ctan%3A/fonts/winfonts/) package yourself in your local TeXMF tree, since, as far as I know, it is not part of MiKTeX nor TeX Live. Don't forget to run `updmap` at the end. Then modify the beginning of your table as:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\fontfamily{arial}\selectfont\small
```

If you want to compile with `XeLaTeX` and Arial is installed on your system, it is simpler: add to your preamble (if not already done):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

and modify the beginning of your table as:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\fontspec{Arial}\small
```